# Deploying an event monitoring app?

Tags: integration, event-monitoring

I'm playing around with the streaming API and Change Data Capture and we got an integration layer that needs to receive all the updates/creations/deletions on Salesforce records. The ingration layer does unfortunately not have a way of subscribing to our event bus.

So, I wonder if it's possible to deploy an app that receives all the events from salesforce and subsequently makes an http request to our integration layer?

Comment: Sure, why not. Take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration) and [Event-Driven Architecture](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/event-driven) decision guides, the options are well covered in there.

Comment: Thanks - that documentation is useful, but I'm still unsure how to actually set up the cometd app - I got it to work locally but not sure how to deploy and/or extend its functionality